# What do you call auto parts that are meant to fit specific vehicles and those that aren't?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some auto parts are tailor fit for one or more vehicles while others aren't. Is there a universally understood name for those two types of parts?

Comment: Is that the case? The reason why I posted it here is I want to hear how vehicle enthusiasts call them, even if it's slang

Comment: It was just a suggestion, as the english stackexchange is very good at exactly this type of question.

Comment: This should not have been migrated. I would expect an auto mechanic to be more knowlegeable about auto parts terminology than a bunch of English majors.

Answer (score 3):

Most parts have applications to several vehicles because the manufacturer

- Used the same part for several years of the same vehicle
- Used the same engine/component in multiple models
- Borrowed technology or used the same supplier as another manufacturer

There are many cases where a part was only used on one make/model/year of a vehicle and the manufacturer used something else the next year.

**Aftermarket** suppliers often find where two "OE" (**Original Equipment**) parts are identical or close enough to identical to combine the applications and offer a single part.

Last, there are cases like exhaust where a **Direct Fit** muffler that matches a specific vehicle is offered whereas a generic muffler that fits a large number of vehicles will also work but might need some custom welding or pipes upon installation.

Comment: Cool! How do you think should non-Direct Fit parts be called, though?

Comment: There is not a specific name.  It is just a part.  In some case you might refer to it as a generic part, but that is normally only when there is also a direct fit component.

Answer (score 2):

I typically think of parts that are not meant for a specific model or models of vehicles to be "universal" or "universal fit" parts.  I can't say where exactly I picked that up though...